# error - ./node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:19:0 Module not found: Can't resolve 'tls'

Tags: javascript, next.js, mysql-connector

I am using this code in our Next JS applications but showing error tls not found.
what should do I do.I have done these things like -

- 1  update Node module
- 2 I have used mysql and mysql2 too.
- 3 npm cache clean --force
- 4 rm -rf node_modules

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'sagenext_web',
});

module.exports = connection;
```

but till now I am facing this issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update your node version by running:

```
nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node
```

If that didn't work, you can try to directly install the package `tls` in your project by running:

```
npm install tls
```

However the tls package is already included in the core packages of node, but it can be useful to separately handle its version

Comment: Thankyou for replying. but now showing this error - 
TypeError: Net.connect is not a function

Comment: What’s your node version you are using?

Comment: currently I am using v18.16.0

Comment: Can you try updating your node version with: `nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node`